# Modifying Font-Locking Entries in Emacs

Tags: emacs, font-lock, text-coloring

How do I make change to `XXX-font-lock-keywords` (typically using `assoc` plus `setcdr`) affect the fontification in `XXX-mode`? It doesn't suffice to simply change the variable to make the change have effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, as a normal user, to modify font-lock entries is to use the function `font-lock-add-keywords` and `font-lock-remove-keywords`. For example:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords c-mode
             '(("\\<\\(FIXME\\):" 1
                font-lock-warning-face t)))
```

Comment: Aha. I think I'll write a replace version myself then using the `add` and `remove`. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

[EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsWiki) is a great source for emacs knowledge, such as [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords).

Comment: But Wikis can change (or sometimes even disappear). Plus, pages on EmacsWiki often address a more general topic, so it's nice when an answer on StackOverflow is a concise, stand-alone source of information. That said, external links can be a great addition to an answer for further reading.

Comment: @Thomas - reposting answers to obvious questions seems like a waste of everyone's time, especially if the answers are easily findable and more detailed than anyone would generally give in an SO post.  i agree that not everything on EmacsWiki is as accessible, but this is font-lock 101.  Not to mention that the answer posted here may become out of date, while EmacsWiki will be maintained over time.